# If sin B = 4/5 with B in Q1, find the following. sin (B/ 2)

Tags: trigonometry

If 
$\sin B = 4/5$ 
with $B$ in Q1, find the following: 
$\sin (B/2)$.

Well, I know the formula is $$\sin{\frac{b}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{1+ \cos A}{2}}$$ and I know its a $3$-$4$-$5$ triangle. I keep getting $\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please tell us what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive answers that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: well I know the fomula is sinb/2 = sqrt1+cosA/2 , and I know its a 3-4-5 triangle I keep getting 2sqrt5/5

Answer (score 1):

What you computed is $\cos(B/2)$.  The half-angle formula for cosine is 
$$\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos\theta}{2}}$$

The half-angle formula for sine is 
$$\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos\theta}{2}}$$
Since $B$ is a first-quadrant angle, so is $B/2$.  Thus, you can obtain the correct answer by taking the positive root.

Answer (score 0):

If B is in Q1, the half angle formula for sine is:$$sin(B/2)=\sqrt{(1-cos(B))/2}$$
$$cos^2(B)=1-sin^2(B)=1-16/25=9/25$$
So $$sin(B/2)=\sqrt{(1-\sqrt{9/25})/2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$$